# Usar Datatimepicker en Modal

Tags: jquery, modal, bootstrap-3

Buenas estoy intentando colocar datatimepicker de bootstrap 3.3.6 a un modal pero no tengo exito , veo la consola y no me aparece nada , ademas de que los datos los estoy cargando desde un ajax y despues are un formulario con algunos de los datos un pedazo del codigo.

```
                    var div_rut_profesional = document.createElement('div');
                    div_rut_profesional.classList.add('col-md-3');
                    row.appendChild(div_rut_profesional);

                    var rut_profesional = document.createElement('p');
                    var textinfo = document.createTextNode("Fecha:");
                    rut_profesional.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                    div_rut_profesional.appendChild(rut_profesional);


                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.classList.add('col-md-3');
                    row.appendChild(div);


                    var div_data = document.createElement('div');
                    div_data.classList.add('input-group');
                    div_data.classList.add('date');
                    div_data.setAttribute("id", "datetimepicker7");
                    div.appendChild(div_data);

                    var rut_profesional_valor = document.createElement('input');
                    rut_profesional_valor.value= element[0].fecha_boleta_medico;
                    rut_profesional_valor.setAttribute("id", "fecha");
                    rut_profesional_valor.classList.add('form-control');
                    rut_profesional_valor.style.maxWidth = "100px";
                    div_data.appendChild(rut_profesional_valor);

                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.classList.add('input-group-addon');
                    div_data.appendChild(span);

                    var span_a = document.createElement('span');
                    span_a.classList.add('glyphicon');
                    span_a.classList.add('glyphicon-calendar');
                    span.appendChild(span_a);
```

Se supone que en el div datetimepicker7 deberia aparecer pero nada :C

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h2>Agregar Boleta</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
        <div id="resultado" name="resultado">

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Despues de 3 horas di con el error tenia que inicializarlo en la funcion que estaba usando  , muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente tu datetimepicker aparece atras de tu modal

intenta poner este estilo

```
<style>
.datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
</style>
```

Fuente:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978254/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-within-modal-window

Comment: $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                locale: 'es'
            });
Se inicializar asi sera tambien .datepicker? , ya intente y de todas formas no funciona :S